NginX Permission denied
Nginx on Ubuntu
I have setup the root in the nginx config file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default to be root /home/username/builds/project; but when trying to view the site I see a 500 error and see the message "/home/username/builds/project/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied) in the logs.
I have run chmod -R 0755 builds to set the access for the builds folder but running sudo -u www-data stat /home/username/builds/ to test the access returns "Permission denied". (sudo -u www-data stat /home/username/ shows it has access).
How can I give www-data access to the builds folder and its files?

You have check and set the permissions not only on the last item of the path, but on all path elements; in this case, I suppose, there is insufficient priviledge on /home/username for www-data:stat. You may give permissions to "enter, but not list", like chmod 0711 /home/username; anybody will be able to cd /home/username and to any sufficiently permitted subdirectories if they know their exact names, but not to ls /home/username or create objects in it.

You should not put your website in your homefolder, but instead under /var/www/yoursite or /srv/yoursite. Check the FHS documention for more info on that topic.
Then you can change the owner of the file to the nginx user to avoid any problems with file permissions.

All of this is debatable.

No, not debatable when those involved do not have some expertise. Those links don't even begin to cover the discussion over where a document root should be. Choosing to change this from what is pre-configured needs a very specific justification and a level of technical expertise not evidenced in the question.

I would definitely recommend against making those files nginx-owned. The web server is the first entity in line for any attacker, and there is no reason for the web server to be modifying those files.
